# Double DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entry error

Tags: php, mysql, csv, duplicates

I was trying to upload a csv file to update a table in my db, but also wanted to prevent duplication. Initially a single DUPLICATE worked but when i added the second condition it didn't work. 
I got "Duplicate entry '1' for key PRIMARY". How can i achieve my aim.

thanks for your help.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO biodata (student_number, fname, lname, course_name, level)
        VALUES('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]', '$data[4]')
        DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE student_number = student_number
        AND course_name = course_name";

 mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Which are the `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE KEY`s in the table?

Comment: only the student_number is a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: So, every student can take just one course, right?

Comment: No not that they can only take one course per semester, but they could actually take a particular course in a semester, while taking other courses alongside it.

Comment: With the design you have now, a student cannot appear in more than 1 row in this table. So no one can take more than one course. Ever. You should re-examine the design. Probably altering the `PRIMARY KEY` or/and splitting information to more tables: one table for student info, one for course info, one for registration info (this table).

Comment: Okay, i've done just that. Tables: students, courses, year1, year2, year3, year4, year5,  and a main table to house the student ID, course ID, and the student scores.

Comment: This sounds ok, except for the many `yearX` tables. I propose you ask a different question, tagged with `database-design`, with your tables and columns.

Comment: i'll do just that. Thanks. Is it possible to tag a particular user in a question using the "@username" function on SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `AND` with comma `,` in the `UPDATE` part.

Use the `VALUES()` syntax to refer to the values passed.

Also, you don't need to update the Primary or Unique Key (that activated the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`):

```
$sql = "
  INSERT into biodata
    (student_number, fname, lname, course_name, level) 
  VALUES
    ('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]', '$data[4]')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                      --- student_number = VALUES(student_number),
                      --- removed
      fname = VALUES(fname),
      lname = VALUES(lname),
      course_name = VALUES(course_name),
      level = VALUES(level)
" ;
```

What the above code does:

If the `INSERT` fails (there is already a student with this `student_number` you are trying to Insert), the `UPDATE` is activated and the 4 other fields are updated.

It's your choice which fields to update. If you want to update for example, only the `course_name` field, just keep that line and remove the rest.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you edited the code, the first code worked well for me. Is there any reason for this? Please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunterstood the meaning of the 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
construct. IT does *not* define a condition for when a duplciate key occurs, but the solution if such an event hast happened. So you can modify the key in some way, that does not result in a duplicate.
The conditions for duplicates is defined via the indexes and (primary) keys within the table definition. So according to your code above, you would add a unique key over student_number and course_name in the table definition.

For more references take a look at the [docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: I only have the student_number as a PRIMARY key.